# Conda environment conflicts with 3rd party software

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, conda

I ran into a problem where my python2 environment is conflicting with the included python and packages of 3rd party software. I get many Runtime Error's. One software I'm writing for has PySide2 already installed. So it complains when I run it under this environment, but I need PySide2 in my environment because there is also stand-alone tools as part of this environment.

I assume the RuntimeError's are coming from the DLLs and other compiled stuff in my python env, so how should I approach this problem?

What I tried initially is to create another conda environment, with just the libs that I need, no python interpreter. Then I would include the site-packages of this second environment to the `PYTHONPATH` of the first one. This way I can run the main one in stand-alone applications and IDE's, and for 3rd party software I just include site-packages in the `PYTHONPATH` without any conda environment. The problem with this is when I run `conda install <mypackage> --no-deps` (to avoid it from install python as a dependency), it defaults to python 3.8 packages, and also leaves me in the dark in terms of what packages dependencies I need and which I don't. I'm thinking for sure there a cleaner way to approach and manage this problem.

Comment: Is there any way of tweaking/modifying the 3rd party software somehow? _One software I'm writing for has PySide2 already installed. So it complains when I run it under this environment, but I need PySide2 in my environment because there is also stand-alone tools as part of this environment._ Do you need a different version of PySide2 than the one the other program is using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't what is the actual error for your case, but I faced this type of conflict between 3rd party python based software and conda several times.I resolve my problem by reinstalling anaconda and check of the option "use anaconda as your default python" at that time. May be it will be helpful for you.